# add params to url in python

Tags: python, json

I would like to pass two parameters to my url(status code & parent id). The json response of the url request is such :

```
{
"page": 1,
"per_page": 10,
"total": 35,
"total_pages": 4,
"data": [
       {
        "id": 11,
        "timestamp": 1565193225660,
        "status": "RUNNING",
        "operatingParams": {
            "rotorSpeed": 2363,
            "slack": 63.07,
            "rootThreshold": 0
        },
        "asset": {
            "id": 4,
            "alias": "Secondary Rotor"
        },
        "parent": {
            "id": 2,
            "alias": "Main Rotor Shaft"
        }
    }]
```

I would like to know how to pass the two parameters in the url. Passing `?status=RUNNING` gives the response of all the devices which have running as status (thats pretty straightforward).
For now I have tried this:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/iot_devices/search?status=RUNNING')
q = resp.json()
print(q)
```

How should I pass in `parentid=2`, so it returns a response with devices which have their parent id=2.Thank you.

Comment: HTTP request libraries like `requests` have well-documented ways to construct query strings for URLs; are you using one? The response isn't of any use to us for describing how to make the request in the first place.

Comment: If the API you are making a request to accepts the `parentid` parameter, you can simply pass it as a second query string parameter: `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/iot_devices/search?status=RUNNING&parentid=2`.

Comment: Well tried that as well, but its not accepting

Answer (score 2):

It's [plainly documented under "Passing Parameters in URLs"](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)  in the Requests docs.

```
resp = requests.get(
    'https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/iot_devices/search',
    params={
        'status': 'RUNNING',
        'parentid': 2,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a second get parameter, use the `&` separator :

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/iot_devices/search?status=RUNNING&parentid=2')
q = resp.json()
print(q)
```

Comment: @AKX answer is probably better as it leverage the requests api in a cleaner, more readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data via get request the process is straight forward note how different values are seperated with '&'.

```
url?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

If you are using Flask for backend then you can access these parameters like.

```
para1=request.args.get("name1")
para2=request.args.get("name2")
```

On the front end you can use ajax to send the request

```
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="url?name1=value1&name2=value2"
xhttp.open("GET",url,true)
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
  {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.send();
```